# Very slow HTML rendering in NSAttributedString on iOS 10.2.1

Tags: ios, objective-c

NSAttributedString html render is causing performance issue on latest OS 10.2.1 
When I checked performance in instruments, it's taking seconds to execute while other requests are taking milliseconds. Compared to other OS, this OS is taking much to execute.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[[NSAttributedString alloc]     initWithData:data                                                                                  options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType}
documentAttributes:nil error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

We used this in tableview cells.

What is the workaround to resolve this?

Comment: NSAttributedString has always been slow to render HTML, I'm not sure this something new with 10.2.1, but maybe Apple broke something.  I'd open a radar.